# RSpec: how can I mixin a module into RSpec test?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, mixins

In my app when user share something he's rating grows. When he tries to share something twice – he will get no additional rating for second try. For application, share callback is triggered by client-side with JS, so, it's just a regular GET-request. So, I need to test this functionality. It's easy. But I'v got several sections with this behavior. Every controller from that sections have method named "rating_from_share", so tests are pretty similar. I think it is good idea  to extract that test's in a mixing and include them where it should be, but I can't figure out, how can I do this.
So, is it real to include a mixing with RSpec to a RSpec test? Maybe something kind of metaprogramming can solve this problem?

P.S. realization of "rating_from_share" method is not really the same but only the output result, so I can't to aggregate it to a superclass and test them here.

EDIT:

According to Vimsha answer, should I do something like this?

```
Module Share
  def share
    it 'should be fun'
      expect(@fun.isFun?).toBe == 'yup' # the @fun is declared in ShareTest
    end
  end
end

describe "Share Test" do
   extend Share
   before :each do
     @fun = Fun.new
   end
   it 'should do test' do
     share # call method from Share module, which has real RSpec code?
   end
end
```

The code is written just here, I'm just trying to get the idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
module Share
  def share
  end
end

describe "Share Test" do
   extend Share
end
```

You can call the methods of the module directly within the tests

Comment: Thanks, and see below: I'm editing my original post.

Comment: Sharing module wouldn't work for what you want to do. I think what you are looking for is shared examples -> https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/example-groups/shared-examples

Answer (score 4):

A common practice in RSpec is to store such logic under `spec/support`. For instance:

```
# spec/support/ratings_macros.rb
module RatingsMacros
  ...
end
```

You then need to load it from your `spec_helper`:

```
# spec/spec_helper.rb
...
RSpec.configure do |config|
  ...
  config.include RatingsMacros
```

You can now call in your tests all the methods defined in the `RatingsMacros` module.

Comment: Wouldn't this include the module to all the tests?

Comment: Yes it would. It's often not an issue.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [shared examples](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/example-groups/shared-examples).

These are typically saved under `spec/support` and loaded via `spec_helper.rb`. Be sure to read the docs to understand how to load the shared code--it is not automagically performed for you.

Once they are defined you can include them like so:

```
# spec/support/decorated_model.rb
shared_examples "decorated_model" do
  it "can be decorated" do
    subject.should respond_to?(:decorate)
  end
end

# my_class_spec.rb
describe MyClass do
  it_behaves_like "decorated_model"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers pollute the test with the module's methods, or involve writing a dummy class. This solution uses the built-in double object as a throwaway object to extend with the module's methods.

```
RSpec.describe Share do
  describe '#share' do
    subject { double.extend(described_class) }
  end

  it 'does something cool' do
    expect(subject.share).to eq 'something_cool'
  end
end
```